# Parse Cloud Code - Send emojis in Push Notification

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to include some unicode chars for an emoji to show as a Push Notification by using Cloud Code.

As an example we prepend the message with an emoji like this:

```
  var textToSend = "\u1f60e " + message;
```

Then this is sent via the `Parse.Push`.

```
data: {
      alert: textToSend
    }
```

However, the emoji is not received just the text. I imagine this is down to the encoding but not sure how this should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of redundant now Parse is closing Jan 2017.